# JavaScript XMLHttpRequest fails to transfer parameters to the server

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I checked the server side, using directly browser GET or jquery.ajax GET to call and it could all return the correct page. That is to say, there is nothing wrong with the server side.

But when I try to use the following codes to do ajax call, I always get a 500 internal server error. The strange thing is I checked the console log and it seems that the parameters are not successfully transferred to the server. The 'type' and 'source' parameters when get to the server are all null.

The relevant codes are as below. The newXMLHttpRequest() is just a method to return correct object for different browser, which has been validated to be correct.

Anyone has any ideas about what goes wrong?

```
function updatePage(html){
    var change =html;
    var contents = document.getElementById("contents");
        contents.innerHTML = change;
}

function submit(){
    var t = document.getElementById("type").value;
    var source = document.getElementById("src").value;

    var req = newXMLHttpRequest();
    req.onreadystatechange = getReadyStateHandler(req, updatePage);
    req.open("GET", "RSSFetchServlet.do",true);
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    req.send("type="+t+"&source="+source);
}
```

Comment: What do you see in Fiddler?

Comment: @SLaks only using Chrome console, so Fiddler could do a better job?

Comment: Are you trying to make a `GET` or `POST` request?

Comment: Did you checked `t` and `source` has values?(inside your `Submit()`)

Comment: @NewDeveloper I checked them and they do have values.

Comment: @Musa I am trying to make a GET request, and also tested with jquery and browser, all correct.

Comment: Did you try to do something like this; `var t = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("type").value);`

Comment: check this:: http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/ajaxgetpost2.shtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem is only when you are using POST can you use request.send method to send parameters. Otherwise, the req won't encapsule the data into the URL.

Answer (score 0):

[A 5xx error](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E500.html) means there's something wrong with you server-side script, not your client-side script. Check for syntax errors, missing `;` and maybe missing declarations.

> Fixing 500 errors - general
>
> This error can only be resolved by fixes to the Web server software. It is not a client-side problem. It is up to the operators of the Web server site to locate and analyse the logs which should give further information about the error.

---

Try appending the parameters on the url instead.

```
req.open("GET", "RSSFetchServlet.do?type="+t+"&source="+source,true);
req.send();
```

Comment: no, getting 500 because I fail to transfer the 'type' and 'source' parameters to the server. Not anything wrong with the server, but the ajax call does not tranfer the 2 parameters correctly...

Comment: @YitongZhou try appending your parameters in the url instead of on `.send()`

Comment: I tried that too, not working... still 500. I am beginning doubting like url encoding issues or any other strange things...I even paste the codes into console.log and run, still 500, which means it is not a bug in the html view page, the only possible location is these js codes.